# Limitar 1 linha em queries com consultas em chave primaria

Tags: mysql, sql, query

Uma das boas práticas sobre otimizações de consultas MySQL, ditadas em uma fonte na internet, diz que é importante limitar como 1 as consultas que já exibem apenas uma linha.

Por exemplo, se eu vou alterar o registro de um usuário, minha consulta atual é assim:

```
select campo1,campo2 from tabela where id=x
```

Neste caso passaria para:

```
select campo1,campo2 from tabela where id=x limit 1
```

Neste caso, considerando que id já é a chave primaria, deve-se fazer essa mudança para otimizar consulta ou, neste caso, a limitação é desnecessária?

Comment: Poderia compartilhar sua fonte Luis? A pessoa deve ter algum motivo para ter escrito isso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É desnecessária a cláusula [limit](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/limit-optimization.html).

[O MySQL fornece uma cláusula de limit](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp) que é usado para especificar o número de registros a serem retornados.

A cláusula LIMIT torna mais fácil para codificar os resultados de várias páginas ou a paginação com o SQL, e é muito útil em tabelas grandes. Voltando um grande número de registros pode ter impacto sobre o desempenho.

Suponha que queremos selecionar todos os registros 1-30 (inclusive) a partir de uma tabela chamada "Pedidos". A consulta SQL, então, parecido com este:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Orders LIMIT 30";
```

Quando a consulta SQL acima é executado, ele retornará os primeiros 30 registros.

E se queremos selecionar registros 16-25 (inclusive)?

Mysql também fornece uma maneira de lidar com isso: Usando offset.

A consulta SQL abaixo diz "retornar apenas 10 registros, começar no registro 16 (offset 15)":

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Orders LIMIT 10 OFFSET 15";
```

Você também pode usar uma sintaxe mais curto para alcançar o mesmo resultado:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Orders LIMIT 15, 10";
```

Observe que os números são invertidos quando você usa uma vírgula.
Se você só precisa de um número especificado de linhas a partir de um conjunto de resultados, use o LIMIT cláusula na consulta.

Mas para um caso com uso de chave primaria o uso dessa cláusula é totalmente desnecessária uma vez que a chave já possui index de busca.

Answer (score 1):

Considerando que o campo `id` está definido como chave primária, não há necessidade de colocar `limit 1`, pois nunca haverá mais que 1 registro.